# node js remote JSON object comes back undefined

Tags: javascript, json, undefined

I am trying to extract the contents of a JSON api but no matter how many ways I try it the console always says undefined. I can get the entire string to display however I am only interested in displaying the Question object. After 8 hours of trying and searching here and on google I am caving in and asking for guidance.

```
var url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=15&type=multiple';

https.get(url, function(res){
var body = '';

res.on('data', function(chunk){
    body += chunk;
});

res.on('end', function(){
    var trivapi = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("Got a response: ", trivapi[0].question);
});
}).on('error', function(e){
  console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing everything right, but missing the `results` wrapper. Here's your code working for me:

```
var https = require('https')
var url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=15&type=multiple';

https.get(url, function(res){
var body = '';

res.on('data', function(chunk){
    body += chunk;
});

res.on('end', function(){
    var trivapi = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("Got a response: ", trivapi.results[0].question);
});
}).on('error', function(e){
  console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much! I searched everywhere for the solution and was about to throw in the towel! You are awesome!!!

Comment: @Palgrave no problem! please accept the answer if it solves your ask :)